# Is it possible to get the codepoint of a CharLiteral at the Crystal compile time in a macro?

Tags: crystal-lang

At the Crystal runtime, this is possible: `'?'.ord`

Is there anything similar for a Crystal macro?: `{% 'a' %}`

(I have no valid use case for this. It's just for esoteric reasons.)

Comment: currently not possible, no. Doc link of what you can do on a CharLiteral: https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/Crystal/Macros/CharLiteral.html

Comment: @bew Thanks.  If you want, you can post your comment as an Answer and I will mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.

[Here is the documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Crystal/Macros/CharLiteral.html) about what you can do on a `CharLiteral`.